# Conditional statements in Partial Views, bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Are conditional statements in Partial Views a bad practice?  For instance, I have a PV that should only render certain markup based on my Model properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Depends***, if your conditions are `View` related in nature (like your scenario) it's fine. If you are mixing domain logic and/or validation logic then that should be a cause for concern. You ultimately want to have a good balance of ***Maintainability***, ***Flexibility*** and ***Performance***.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see anything wrong in having conditional statements in your Partials. I guess you’d have to let us know more about the entire context/situation before we blindly say “yeah…sure! Or the opposite”

For example, I have a Partial View that is strongly typed to an IEnumerable.

The first thing I do is verify if the Model isn’t null or if it has any values (note this may or may not reflect your current case).

```
if(Model == null || !Model.MyList.Any())
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something else…
     foreach(var item in Model.MyList)
     {
         If(item.MyProperty == “4”)
          {
              //render this HTML
          }
     }
}
```

But then again…it is hard to give a correct answer, without seeing anything…perhaps you may need to reengineer who knows!